# Помогите разобраться с кодом. Двумерные массивы

Tags: c

Пытаюсь разобраться с двумерными массивами,сейчас остановился на заполнении и выводе массива.Но,выводится вообще не то,что ожидается+иногда вылазит SigSegv.Код проверил несколько раз,ошибок не смог найти.

```
int main() 
{
    const int n=6,m=3;
int massiv[n][m],i=0,j=0;
printf("Spisok chisel v massive");
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{

for(int j=0; i<m; j++)
{
massiv[i][j]=(rand() % 200)-100;
printf("\nmassiv[%i][%i]={%i}",i,j,massiv[i][j]);
}
}

     getchar();
}
```

Выводится

```
Spisok chisel v massive
massiv[0][0]={-59}
massiv[0][1]={-33}
massiv[0][2]={34}
massiv[0][3]={0}
massiv[0][4]={69}
massiv[0][5]={24}
massiv[0][6]={-22}
massiv[0][7]={58}
massiv[0][8]={62}
massiv[0][9]={-36}
massiv[0][10]={5}
massiv[0][11]={45}
massiv[0][12]={-19}
massiv[0][13]={-73}
massiv[0][14]={61}
massiv[0][15]={-9}
massiv[0][16]={95}
massiv[0][17]={42}
massiv[0][18]={-73}
massiv[0][19]={-64}
massiv[0][20]={91}
massiv[0][21]={-96}
massiv[0][2]={34}
massiv[0][3]={53}
massiv[0][4]={-8}
massiv[0][5]={82}
massiv[0][6]={-79}
massiv[0][7]={16}
massiv[0][8]={18}
massiv[0][9]={-5}
massiv[0][10]={-53}
massiv[0][11]={26}
massiv[0][12]={71}
massiv[0][13]={38}
massiv[0][14]={-31}
massiv[0][15]={12}
massiv[0][16]={-33}
massiv[0][17]={-1}
massiv[0][18]={-65}
massiv[0][19]={-6}
massiv[0][20]={3}
massiv[0][21]={-89}
massiv[0][22]={22}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for(int j=0; i<m; j++)` 
Вот в этом месте у вас должно быть j < m  по логике, возможно в этом причина. Вложенный цикл не завершится, т.к условие никогда не станет ложным.